# Diacritics in code blocks

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

Just noted that there is a little bug regarding diacritics in code blocks. See the screenshot:

> [image]

Why are `Ionic` and `Biz` blue and the other part of code is black?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the Google Code Prettifier doesn't count non-ASCII characters in identifiers and type names.

In 'unknown' code, anything starting with an uppercase ASCII character, followed by a mix of upper and lowercase ASCII letters is considered a *type name* and marked up as such. The `ă` in your name is not an ASCII character, so the type name stops before that point as far as the prettifier is concerned. See the [regular expression in the prettifier source code](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/prettify.js#949).

In this case, it is just highlighting non-code with a best-guess effort. It might be a bug if you encountered this in a programming language that allows for a broad range of Unicode characters in identifiers and type names (such as Python 3), but that'd be something to report to the [Google Code Prettify project](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), not to Stack Exchange. See the [SE syntax highlighting FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work).

Note that they already have this on their TODO list, however. [Two lines before the regular expression that picks up only part of your name](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/prettify.js#947) is the comment:

```js
// TODO(mikesamuel): recognize non-latin letters and numerals in idents
```

There is an existing [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=269), apparently the problem lies with JavaScript's lack of decent Unicode support in regular expressions.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the current state-of-the-art way to address Javascript’s pessimal Unicode non-handling is via [the `XRegExp` addon](http://xregexp.com/plugins/). It’s now broken out into smaller pieces so you can get only as much as you need, of which the `\p{Letter}` General Category is the most common one, included in the base addon; that would probably suffice here. You can also pull in the rest of the General Categories, the Script properties, &c at your leisure and pleasure. See also [these SO Q&As about `XRegExp`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=xregexp).

Comment: @tchrist: the bug report I linked to also recommends using XRegExp to solve the issue. Further discussion about this is probably best directed to the project, not here.

Answer (score 1):

[Martijn Pieters's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238715) explains what's going on in this specific case. But you might have weird colors for other reasons than non-ASCII characters. If the content of your code block isn't code in a programming language, tell the syntax highlighting engine not to use any colors by putting a [magic comment](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) immediately before the code block.

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

    $ npm init
    …
    author: (Ionică Bizău)
```

Comment: Indeed, but this code is expected to have `lang-shell` highlight.

Comment: @IonicăBizău; but if it is just *one line* of shell command and the rest is arbitrary output, then perhaps switching of highlighting is appropriate.